# Show that $X'\neq X^*$ for $X$ t.v.s. with $dim X=\infty$ where the neighbourhood filter of $0$ has a countable basis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space with $\mathrm{dim}\ X=\infty$ where the neighbourhood filter of $0$ has a countable basis. Show that $X'\neq X^*$

$X'$ is the topological dual and $X^*$ is the algebraic dual.

> What I tried: We need to find $f$ such that $f \in X^*$ but $f \notin X'$.

Let $I$ be the index set of the basis of $X$ and $(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ the countable basis of the neighbourhood filter of $0$.

Define $f(b_i)=0$ for $i \in \mathbb N$ and $f(b_i)=i$ for $i \in I\setminus \mathbb N$.

So $f$ is unbounded and therefore not continuous. Which implies that $f \notin X'$